# Stream Analytics UDF - using the output from one UDF in another

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

The following code results in my GT2HP value being null in the follow on UDFs:

```
SELECT 
    UDF.GT2HP(Collect()) as GT2HP,
    UDF.LPLPReturns(Collect()) as LPLPReturns,
    UDF.LPGasHeater(Collect()) as LPGasHeater,
    UDF.HPRaisedSW(Collect(), AVG(GT2HP)) as HPRaisedSW,
    UDF.HPCustomerDemand(Collect(), AVG(GT2HP)) as HPCustomerDemand
INTO SQLDWUKSTEAMLOSS
FROM IotHubInput
WHERE IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId = 'uk-iotedge'
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 60)
```

The following code works:

```
SELECT 
    UDF.GT2HP(Collect()) as GT2HP,
    UDF.LPLPReturns(Collect()) as LPLPReturns,
    UDF.LPGasHeater(Collect()) as LPGasHeater,
    UDF.HPRaisedSW(Collect(), UDF.GT2HP(Collect())) as HPRaisedSW,
    UDF.HPCustomerDemand(Collect(), UDF.GT2HP(Collect())) as HPCustomerDemand
INTO SQLDWUKSTEAMLOSS
FROM IotHubInput
WHERE IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId = 'uk-iotedge'
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 60)
```

Obviously the second code is way more computationally expensive than the first and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

I'd like to use the output of the first UDF in my follow on UDFs, but it seems to pass on null. All the select statements appear to execute in parallel not serial, which probably explains the null.

Is there a way to use the output of one UDF in another UDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `GT2HP` column referenced in the `AVG(GT2HP)` is always null is due to the SQL semantics.
Columns in the SELECT clause can only refer to sources referenced in FROM, and since there is no `IotHubInput.GT2HP` - it is interpreted as null.

If you separate your query into multiple steps, as Vignesh suggested you will end up with the first step just computing the `COLLECT` over the 60 sec window:

```
SELECT Collect() AS c
WHERE IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId = 'uk-iotedge'
FROM IotHubInput
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 60)
```

Let's name it `step1`. Now, since you are grouping only by a window, you will have just one value of column `c` every 60 sec.
Any aggregation over this is not necessary unless you increase the size of the window to aggregate more than one value...

So the AVG in the AVG(GT2HP) is unnecessary.
The second step then will be:

```
SELECT
    c,
    GT2HP = UDF.GT2HP(c)
FROM step1
```

Let's call this step `step2`.
Now the final selection will be:

```
SELECT 
    GT2HP,
    UDF.LPLPReturns(c) as LPLPReturns,
    UDF.LPGasHeater(c) as LPGasHeater,
    UDF.HPRaisedSW(c, GT2HP) as HPRaisedSW,
    UDF.HPCustomerDemand(c, GT2HP) as HPCustomerDemand
INTO SQLDWUKSTEAMLOSS
FROM step2
```

And putting it all together:

```
WITH step1 AS (
    SELECT Collect() AS c
    WHERE IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId = 'uk-iotedge'
    FROM IotHubInput
    GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 60)
),
step2 AS (
    SELECT
        c,
        GT2HP = UDF.GT2HP(c)
    FROM step1
)

SELECT 
    GT2HP,
    UDF.LPLPReturns(c) as LPLPReturns,
    UDF.LPGasHeater(c) as LPGasHeater,
    UDF.HPRaisedSW(c, GT2HP) as HPRaisedSW,
    UDF.HPCustomerDemand(c, GT2HP) as HPCustomerDemand
INTO SQLDWUKSTEAMLOSS
FROM step2
```

Comment: Thanks, let me give this a go and get back to you.

Comment: I have tested and verified that this does indeed work. Thank for for laying it out clearly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as two statements. First one selects Collect() and avg() with a group by. Second select uses the results to call UDF.

Comment: Brilliant, using multiple SELECT code blocks worked a treat.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work.

     SELECT UDF.Function(val) as val
      WHERE clauses go here
     SELECT AVG(val)

Val still returns as null.

Describe what you mean as 'Write it as two statements'?